# 404 not found Error in AGEDB-INC/Cloud-Express signup and signup

Tags: reactjs, express, apache-age

I'm running the [the AGEDB-INC/Cloud-Express](https://github.com/AGEDB-INC/Cloud-Express) Project on my system.

I installed the necessary dependencies using the following command in root folder

> npm run setup

using node version `20.3.1`

and then run the project in node version `14.16.0` using the following command

> npm start

the project is running fine but there was initially an error: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

it was due to front-end was requesting on port 4000 and the backend was running on port 3001, I resolved this issue, but now a new error appears: `404 not Found`

I think it issue with routes but unable to resolve it

[image: Image showing error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection refused error is an indication that the backend MongoDB server is not running.
If you already have a valid environment variables in your `.env` setup, (note: refer to the cloud-express/backend/readme file), then open a new terminal and run:

```
cd backend 
node index
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you actually have your `MongoDB` running. It would be good if you also verify whether you have set up the environment variables correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In cloudexpress you have frontend & backend and you need to run them individually.

Here are the commands:

**Frontend:**

```
npm run start
```

**Backend:** In other terminal.

```
cd backend
node index
```

or

```
cd backend
node index.js
```

Make sure to have active internet connection, because for login/signup you will be communicating with hosted mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

The error yourefacing is occuring because the URL or route you're providing is incorrect. Check the  backend logs for information regarding the incoming requests and make sure that the right URL is being used.